# Complex vector dot a real vector

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, projection

If we have two vectors $w$ and $v$ (members of $\mathbb{C^n})$ I understand that

$v \cdot w = v^*w$.

But what happens if we have one real vector and one complex, say $v = \begin{bmatrix}
    2 \\ -5 \\ 1 
\end{bmatrix}$ and $w = \begin{bmatrix}
    i \\ 2+i \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}$

Taking the dot product in the usual way I would get $2i-5(2+i)+1 = -9-3i$

If I instead take the conjugate transpose of $w$ I would get

$[-i, 2-i, 1] \cdot  \begin{bmatrix}
    2 \\ -5 \\ 1 
\end{bmatrix} = -9+3i$. What is correct?

Comment: With complex vectors, $v^*w\ne w^*v$.

Comment: In french, the complex dot product is said to be "sesqui-linéaire", don't know how to say it in english (but I'm sure I will in a short while :-) : $w\cdot v = \overline{v\cdot w}$. What is real is the result of the associated quadratic form : $v\cdot v=v^\ast v$ is a real number.

Comment: Your first paragraph is not correct... I think you are mixing up the definition of inner product and an explicit expression for it. Maybe even mixing up euclidean vector space and Hilbert space

Comment: Does that mean it's not possible to take the dot product of the two vectors I provided?

Comment: Why not? You just need to determine which definition of the inner product to use. For Hilbert space for functions represented in some basis you have $\langle a|b \rangle = a^* \cdot b$. For Euclidean space you have  $\langle a|b \rangle = a \cdot b$ . I think. Anyway, you should know the definition for your case

Comment: Ok, thank you..

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS It is also called sesquilinear in English.

Comment: @Ernie060 : I knew someone would translate it for me :)